# Operating on each item of a Variant

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a function which operates on each element of a [N x M] variant.  Simple stuff in Matlab, but VBA does my head in:

Flavour 1 - does not work. Ia is considered as [1 x 1] Double.

```
' read data from file
Dim Lia()
Dim Ia as Variant
Dim sign()
Dim ncol As Integer
Dim maxcol As Integer

Lia = src_wb.Worksheets("SIL").Range("BJ2:CJ2").Value
sign = src_wb.Worksheets("SIL").Range("CE2:DF2").Value
For ncol = 1 To UBound(Lia, 2) - LBound(Lia, 2) + 1
      Ia = 0.000000000001 * 10 ^ (Lia(1, ncol) / 10) * sign(1, ncol)
Next ncol
```

Flavour 2 - I tried dimensioning Ia with the correct size so I can use the `(1, ncol)` way of addressing each element. Get a complaint that you "a constant expression is needed". How useless is that?

```
Dim Ia(1 To 1, 1 To maxcol)
```

Flavour 3 - try the `(1, ncol)` way anyway, you never know... Get a rebuff on poor indexing.

```
' read data from file
Dim Lia()
Dim Ia as Variant
Dim sign()
Dim ncol As Integer
Dim maxcol As Integer

Lia = src_wb.Worksheets("SIL").Range("BJ2:CJ2").Value
sign = src_wb.Worksheets("SIL").Range("CE2:DF2").Value
For ncol = 1 To UBound(Lia, 2) - LBound(Lia, 2) + 1
      Ia(1, ncol) = 0.000000000001 * 10 ^ (Lia(1, ncol) / 10) * sign(1, ncol)
Next ncol
```

How is this done correctly?  Ideally, I wouldn't wanna loop anyway, but use the `For Each x in Variant` approach - but that I didn't understand either. So, any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to update the `Lia` row **in-place** or put the results in **another row** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
' read data from file
Dim Lia() as Variant
Dim Ia() as Variant
Dim sign() as Variant
Dim ncol As Integer
Dim maxcol As Integer

Lia = src_wb.Worksheets("SIL").Range("BJ2:CJ2").Value
sign = src_wb.Worksheets("SIL").Range("CE2:DF2").Value

Redim Ia(1 to UBound(Lia, 2))

For ncol = 1 To UBound(Lia, 2)
      Ia(ncol) = 10 ^ (Lia(1, ncol) / 10 - 12) * sign(1, ncol)
Next ncol
```

Chip Pearson has a good intro to reading range data into VBA: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Also, as noted in the comments, if you intend to write `Ia` back to the workbook, you may want to make it 2-dimensional.
To answer your question about looping with a `For Each`, the following would sum each element in `Ia`:

```
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim dblSum As Double

For Each vItem In Ia
    dblSum = dblSum + vItem
Next vItem
```

However, using a `For Each` wouldn't work well in your code because you need the index for `Ia`, `Lia`, and `sign` to move in lockstep.

Comment: How about `Redim Ia(1 to 1, 1 to UBound(Lia, 2))`

Comment: The original answer was missing the indexing on Ia (just like in the question's first example code). I updated it.